# Woocommerce Tax Setup Price not displaying correclty

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Consider my shop ships to two states "Kerala" and "Mumbai", and both have different taxes as shown below while shipping:

```
Kerala  - Taxes - 9%(State GST), 9% (Central GST) and 1%(Kerala Flood Cess)
Mumbai - Taxes - 18% (Integrated GST)
```

Also I need to show product price inclusive of all taxes in shop page, product page etc. Only checkout page needs to show the split of taxes.

How can I achieve the same with woo-commerce tax settings. I tried below things:

```
Woocommerce general settings => Default customer location => No Location by default
Display prices in the shop => Inclusive of Tax
Display prices in the checkout => Inclusive of Tax
```

In Tax settings `Calculate Tax based on => Customer Billing Address`

Problem is once we enter the billing address the store is showing price exclusive of tax.

Please explain how to properly configure this requirement.

Comment: in the tax settings, on "Prices entered with tax" choose "yes"

Comment: @Kaperto already its like that price inclusive of tax

Comment: ₹2,398 (includes ₹181.09 9% SGST, ₹181.09 9% CGST, ₹23.74 1% KFC) if state is KERALA, 

when state is changed total Value changes: ₹2,377.85 (includes ₹362.72 18% IGST)

It should be like : ₹2,398 (includes ₹431.64 18% IGST)

Comment: @Kaperto does it have anything to do with this? woocommerce_adjust_non_base_location_prices hook